# Rspec testing complex code with undefined variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

Just need alittle bit of help with rspec testing... very new to it and dont quite know how to test this piece of code

```
# Get a list of tasks recently used by the user
    recent_task_ids = Effort.all( :select => "project_task_id",
                                  :conditions => { :user_id => @user_id },
                                  :group => "project_task_id",
                                  :order => "MAX( week_commencing )" )


    # For each of the task ids, get the actual project task records
    @recent_tasks = []
    recent_task_ids.each do |effort|
      if ProjectTask.find_by_id( effort.project_task_id ) != nil
        @recent_tasks.push( ProjectTask.find( effort.project_task_id ) )
      end
    end
```

Not sure if your even supposed to test undefined variables this way but any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stub out the Effort.all method.

```
it "tests with nil values" do
  Effort.stub(:all).and_return(nil)
end
```

Source: http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/stubs.html and  http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/

Comment: thanks two questions. 1, on the examples theres a ! . and 2 where youve put nil, would i be right in saying id put the attributes that im looking for? so Effort.stub!(:all).and_return(:select => "project_task_id",
                                  :conditions => { :user_id => @user_id },
                                  :group => "project_task_id",
                                  :order => "MAX( week_commencing )")

Comment: stub! is deprecated in RSpec2.  2)  You are testing the properties of when Effort.all returns nil, so leave the return value as nil.  If you do not stub for the other tests then they should work as they currently do.